# Not able to convert ER diagram to xml

Tags: xml, entity-relationship

I need to convert a ER diagram to XML [ER diagram Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0ML3.png)
**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<company companyname="abc" address="hj">
    <department dname="dfsdf" deptphoneno="1232321" deptfaxno="2323" deptemail="fefsf">
        <employee empid="fsd" ename="fuehuf" emailid="fhueh" phoneno="364764"> </employee>
        <employee empid="fsd" ename="fuehuf" emailid="fhueh" phoneno="364764"> </employee>
        <contractEmployee name="fdsf" phoneno="12345"> </contractEmployee>
    </department>
</company>
```

Can someone please have a look and tell me If I wrote the correct xml or not? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the `contractEmployee` is also an employee . in my opinion your database tables should be something like this :

**1-** company(Id,name,addr)

**2-** department(Id, name, phoneNo, mail, company_id)

**3-** employee(Id, name, phoneNo, mail, depId)

as I said I assume that `contractEmployee` is also an employee. if it is different please provide more information of it.

if the company name is unique you can use that instead of company_id in department table.also if department name is unique you can use it instead of depId in employee table.